# Subsets of combining two list

Tags: python

Say you have two lists that you're gonna combine

```
(a, b, c)
(d, e, f)
```

How would I go the process of finding a new list filled with subsets of length 3. Such as

```
[(a, b, c), (a, b, f), (a, e, c), (a, e, f), (d, e, c), (d, e, f), (d, b, c),
 (d, b, f)]
```

Would prefer logic code with for but while loops works too

Comment: are `a, b, c, d, e, f` variables or strings? please fix or elaborate if so. This doesn't change the answer but please post correct code as I assume they are strings

Comment: You combine the lists.  You generate the combinations of length 3.  Each of these is a simple, well-documented step.  Where are you thinking Stack Overflow should help?

Comment: @Jab they are arbitrary variable

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are not doing `combinations` but rather a [grid expand](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/expand.grid)/ [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Here is the exact results you have:

### Python

```
from itertools import product
mat = [('a', 'b', 'c'),('d','e', 'f')]
list(product(*zip(*mat))) 
[('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('a', 'b', 'f'),
 ('a', 'e', 'c'),
 ('a', 'e', 'f'),
 ('d', 'b', 'c'),
 ('d', 'b', 'f'),
 ('d', 'e', 'c'),
 ('d', 'e', 'f')]
```

### R

```
mat <- list(c('a', 'b', 'c'), c('d','e', 'f'))
rev(expand.grid(unname(rev(do.call(rbind.data.frame, mat)))))
  Var3 Var2 Var1
1    a    b    c
2    a    b    f
3    a    e    c
4    a    e    f
5    d    b    c
6    d    b    f
7    d    e    c
8    d    e    f
```

### EDIT:

### Simpler R code

```
expand.grid(purrr::transpose(mat))
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    a    b    c
2    d    b    c
3    a    e    c
4    d    e    c
5    a    b    f
6    d    b    f
7    a    e    f
8    d    e    f
```

Of course you can arrange it the way you want:

```
rev(expand.grid(rev(purrr::transpose(mat))))
  Var3 Var2 Var1
1    a    b    c
2    a    b    f
3    a    e    c
4    a    e    f
5    d    b    c
6    d    b    f
7    d    e    c
8    d    e    f
```

Comment: Wow, you answered in two languages. Impresive!

Comment: @BuddyBob different syntax but exactly same logic

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
import itertools
mat=[('a', 'b', 'c'),('d','e', 'f')]
#first arg = iterable
#second arg = length of outputted tuple
print(list(itertools.combinations([lett for tup in mat for lett in tup], 3)))
```

output

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'e'), ('a', 'b', 'f'), ('a', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'e'), ('a', 'c', 'f'), ('a', 'd', 'e'), ('a', 'd', 'f'), ('a', 'e', 'f'), ('b', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'f'), ('b', 'd', 'e'), ('b', 'd', 'f'), ('b', 'e', 'f'), ('c', 'd', 'e'), ('c', 'd', 'f'), ('c', 'e', 'f'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
```

Comment: R translation - `combn(c(x,y), 3, simplify=FALSE)`

Comment: Yep. Just thought I'd throw it out there since the post was tagged `[r]` as well.

Comment: You could simply do `list(combinations(sum(mat, ())))`

Answer (score 1):

Below are some base R options:

```
> expand.grid(asplit(rbind(x1, x2), 2))
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    a    b    c
2    d    b    c
3    a    e    c
4    d    e    c
5    a    b    f
6    d    b    f
7    a    e    f
8    d    e    f
```

or

```
> Reduce(function(a, b) c(outer(a, b, paste)), asplit(rbind(x1, x2), 2))
[1] "a b c" "d b c" "a e c" "d e c" "a b f" "d b f" "a e f" "d e f"
```

## Data

```
x1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
x2 <- c("d", "e", "f")
```